# Delete Time series in prometheus without API

Tags: centos, prometheus, monitoring, grafana

I am monitoring a instance and changed its target IP. now when I graph it in grafana, there is 2 lines(with different color) showing with the tail of first line the head of the second line.

My goal is to remove the first line and just show the updated, second line.

My attempt is to adjust the time frame in grafana which works but it will affect all the instances that are not changed.

My second attempt is to remove the time-series in prometheus but the API was not enabled and restarting would cause a hiccup in the prometheus system (which is not good in monitoring).
It also said [here](https://www.shellhacks.com/prometheus-delete-time-series-metrics/) that time-series can only be deleted via API but this is `2018`. I was wondering if it is now possible to remove time-series without API.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, the only way to remove time series is using the API
2. Yes, restarting would cause a hiccup, but let's be practical: the downtime is really very small.